# Grammar checker extension for Firefox

Tags: firefox, spell-checker, english, grammar

I'm using Mozilla Firefox, and I'm writing a lot of articles on different sites. I need an extension that will check the text I write (in English) and suggest me how to fix it if there are any grammar mistakes.
Which are the best extensions that do such thing?

Something that can detect that "She eat fish." is not correct is perfect.

Comment: For what language(s)? Is it OK to only check separate words, or do you really need grammar? For instance something that can detect that "She eat fish." is not correct? The more checks the better I guess :-)

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, I edited the question.I need it for English. something that can detect that "She eat fish." is not correct is perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check out [Grammarly](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/grammarly-1/) they have plugins for FireFox, Chrome, Outlook and Word.

They also have free and paid plans.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one that turned up in a Google search: [LanguageTool Grammar Checker by Daniel Naber](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/languagetool/?src=recommended). It's a Firefox add-on, so it's free, and it's highly rated by a goodly number of reviewers.

Answer (score 0):

We recently released an add-on that gives different types of grammatical suggestions for Firefox here: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/sapling-writing-assistant/

Feedback very much welcome!